# Django 2.1.1, IntegrityError, NOT NULL constraint failed: papers_paper.seminary_id

Tags: python, django, null, constraints

Python version: 3.7
Django version 2.1.1

I'm new to django and I'm teaching myself mostly with help of tutorials and 'trial and error'. I have searched stackoverflow, but none of the previous questions seem to fit to my problem. For example, they refer to blank CharFields, which I don't think is my problem here.

I thought, that I linked the two classes **Seminary** and **Paper** via the ForeignKey.
Right now I can add **Seminary** to the database via the appropiate form and display it the way I want it.
But with a second form considering the class **Paper**, django gives me the error:

> Request Method:   POST
>
> Exception Type:   IntegrityError
>
> Exception Value: NOT NULL constraint failed: papers_paper.seminary_id

**papers** is my app, btw

Here is models.py, without meta:

```
class Seminary(models.Model):
slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
seminary_type = models.CharField(max_length=25, choices=choices.SEMINARY_TYPE_CHOICES)
seminary_title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
seminary_year = models.IntegerField(choices=choices.YEAR_CHOICES, default=datetime.now().year)
summer_winter = models.CharField(max_length=6, choices=choices.SEASON_CHOICES, default="S")

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('papers:paper-detail', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})

def __str__(self):
    return self.seminary_title


def create_slug(instance, new_slug=None):
    slug = slugify(instance.seminary_title)
    if new_slug is not None:
        slug = new_slug
    qs = Seminary.objects.filter(slug=slug)
    exists = qs.exists()
    if exists:
        new_slug = "%s-%s" % (slug, qs.first().pk)
        return create_slug(instance, new_slug=new_slug)
    return slug


def pre_save_post_receiver(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
    if not instance.slug:
        instance.slug = create_slug(instance)


pre_save.connect(pre_save_post_receiver, sender=Seminary)


class Paper(models.Model):
    seminary = models.ForeignKey(Seminary, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
    paper_title = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False, help_text="Please enter the title ")
    author = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    upload_paper = ContentTypeRestrictedFileField(
        upload_to='papers/pdf',
        content_types=['application/pdf'],
        max_upload_size=5242880,
        blank=True
    )

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('papers:paper-index', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})
```

Here is views.py:

```
class IndexView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'papers/index.html'
    context_object_name = 'all_papers'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Seminary.objects.all()


class DetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Seminary
    template_name = 'papers/detail.html'


class SeminaryCreate(CreateView):
    model = Seminary
    fields = ['summer_winter',
              'seminary_year',
              'seminary_type',
              'seminary_title',
              ]


class PaperCreate(CreateView):
    model = Paper
    fields = [
        'paper_title',
        'author',
        'upload_paper',
    ]
```

I'm sure, that I'm mixing something up. If there is more information necessary for me to provide, please ask, and I will add it to my question.
Thanks in advance!

Edit:

I added **seminary** to the view **PaperCreate** as recommended by @bluegrounds
Now it gives me the following error instead.

> Exception Type:   ImproperlyConfigured
>
> Exception Value:  No URL to redirect to.  Either provide a url or
>   define a get_absolute_url method on the Model.

Anyhow, there is not supposed to be a choice of the seminar: serveral papers each allocated to only one specific seminar.

Complete Traceback, after changing the view **PaperCreate**:

```
Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/papers/seminartitel15/add/

Django Version: 2.1.1
Python Version: 3.7.0
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'transcript.apps.TranscriptConfig',
 'biblio.apps.BiblioConfig',
 'papers.apps.PapersConfig',
 'crispy_forms']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback:

File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py" in get_success_url
  116.                 url = self.object.get_absolute_url()

File "/home/bjoern/MyCode/PycharmProjects/websiteTwo/websiteTwo/papers/models.py" in get_absolute_url
  68.         return reverse('papers:paper-index', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})

During handling of the above exception ('Paper' object has no attribute 'slug'), another exception occurred:

File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  34.             response = get_response(request)

File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  126.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  124.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in view
  68.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in dispatch
  88.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py" in post
  172.         return super().post(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py" in post
  142.             return self.form_valid(form)

File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py" in form_valid
  126.         return super().form_valid(form)

File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py" in form_valid
  57.         return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())

File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py" in get_success_url
  119.                     "No URL to redirect to.  Either provide a url or define"

Exception Type: ImproperlyConfigured at /papers/seminartitel15/add/
Exception Value: No URL to redirect to.  Either provide a url or define a get_absolute_url method on the Model.
```

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('papers/new/', views.SeminaryCreate.as_view(), name='seminary-add'),
    path('papers/', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='paper-index'),
    path('papers/<str:slug>/', views.DetailView.as_view(), name='paper-detail'),
    path('papers/<str:slug>/add/', views.PaperCreate.as_view(), name='paper-add'),

]
```

Edit_2:
I couldn't solve the whole problem, but the advice by @bluegrounds was helpful.
In addition I changed **get_absolute_url** of the class **paper** to

```
 def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('papers:paper-detail', args=[str(self.seminary.slug)])
```

as suggested in the documentation.

Now I have trouble with my template, but I will set up a new question for that.
Thanks a lot so far!

Comment: Please add complete traceback.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You may want to clarify the version of Python and Django you're using; I think you mean you're using Django 2.1 with Python 3.7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm no expert neither but I think it's because your PaperCreate view doesn't have a way to link a Paper object to a Seminary object like how the database is expecting. Each Paper object should have the id of a Seminary object because you've added that in the Paper model class:

```
class Paper(models.Model):
    seminary = models.ForeignKey(Seminary, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
```

and because the ForeignKey field can't be null, it's raising a `NOT NULL constraint failed: papers_paper.seminary_id`

So maybe do this, see if it works:

```
class PaperCreate(CreateView):
    model = Paper
    fields = [
        'seminary',
        'paper_title',
        'author',
        'upload_paper',
    ]
```

If I remember correctly, CreateView should take care of displaying a dropdown menu on the webpage that has the available seminary objects.

*Side note*

Are you sure about the primary key attribute here?

```
class Paper(models.Model):
    seminary = models.ForeignKey(Seminary, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
```

Comment: I added 'seminary' to the fields. I think that was it, but now I get a different error. I edit my post.

Comment: The new error is: "Exception Type: ImproperlyConfigured, Exception Value: No URL to redirect to. Either provide a url or define a get_absolute_url method on the Model."

Comment: I suggest you to start reading the error message. This error is happening because Django doesn't know where to redirect after form submissions. So you have two option you can define success_url in your PaperCreate class or you can define get absolute url in your Paper models.<br>

Comment: Read about get_absolute url https://godjango.com/67-understanding-get_absolute_url/

Comment: I don't know how much code you've written until now, but from what I can see there's still a lot missing. This specific error you're now getting is asking you to write the `get_absolute_url` method which is used to redirect to an object's DetailView which has to be written inside the Model class. And you also have to write a DetailView for both your Paper and your Seminary objects. Now you have actually a DetailView class for Seminary objects but I'd suggest renaming it to SeminaryDetail, and then make the other PaperDetail class. If you need more help, ask another question with your new code.

Comment: And please choose the most helpful answer by clicking on the tick under its score at its top left side.

Comment: @ArpitSvt I didn't understand why exactly Django doesn't know where to redirect as it works fine with the class 'Seminary', but not with 'Paper'. As you can see I want to work with get_absolute_url. But Django won't accept it in case of the class 'Paper', and I don't know why.

Comment: @bluegrounds I wanted to redirect both model classes to the same view with the url ''papers/<str:slug>/' '. Is that not possible?

Answer (score 0):

IntegrityError, NOT NULL constraint failed: papers_paper.seminary_id.
This error means that you have Foreign Key to Seminary in Paper model with not null constraint but while creating a Paper object you are not passing the value of the Seminary(Foreign Key).

Comment: What does FK mean?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. How would I pass the Foreign Key?

Comment: Since you are using Django Generic Class based View, you can append 'seminary' in the fields of PaperCreate class.